# How to add missing flags for countries in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, country

I created a sheet with these country names:

United Kingdom
Spain
Portugal
Germany
France
Netherlands
Belgium
Poland
Czech Republic
Slovakia

I then selected the cells and hit the `Geography` button.

In the neighbouring cells I entered the formula `=A1.Image`, repeating for each cell, which displayed the flag for those countries.

France was not displayed, but I can fix that by selecting the `France` cell, opening the menu and going `Data Type > Change` and choosing the flag which shows up. This updates `France` to `Metropolitan France`, which fixes the problem for France.

Belgium, Czech Republic and Slovakia still show `#FIELD!`.

[image]

The same fix for those cells does not work and I can't find an option to import or update/refresh the missing flags (that works.)

How do I fix these?